# MySQL Circular Replication does not throw error, but is not syncing. Any ideas?

Tags: mysql, replication, vmware

We are using MySQL Circular replication (2 servers in a master-slave setting with each other) for an implementation with both servers is different regions.

Previously, we had the entire setup running flawlessly, but the VMWare vendor had to upgrade their underlying infrastructure and had us move the sites over to a new infrastructure. They cloned over our entire app including the servers so we had to do next to no configuration on the actual VMs. However, once traffic was diverted over, one of the servers has gotten into a wierd setting where all flags (`Slave_IO_Running: Yes, Slave_SQL_Running: Yes, Seconds_Behind_Master: 0`) are showing that all is well, but in reality, the Master_Log_File and Read_Master_Log_Pos variables are not changing at all and seem to be stuck (also causing our NMS not to be able to catch this). Same was verified by creating 2 tables, one on each side. Changes on B are appearing almost immediately on A, but the same is not occurring for changes on A to B.

We tried debugging it and when nothing else worked, we just got 2 new VMs, tested out replication again and moved the site over. Within 5 hours, we were at the same scenario again. Below are the outputs of `Show Master Status` and `Show Slave Status` of the newer servers.

On a side note, there is another simple slave that is also connected to db03 that is fully synced and is following db03 diligently, which proves the issue is not on db03 end. Also, the original setup on the older infrastructure is also still running strong.

```
Output from db-04-db (Database 04) ..
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.000191
         Position: 40328871
     Binlog_Do_DB: <databases>
 Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
Executed_Gtid_Set: 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: db-03-db
                  Master_User: reple
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000293
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 154
               Relay_Log_File: db04-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000293
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 154
              Relay_Log_Space: 154
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 5949f340-64f7-11ec-82b5-00505601012c
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
Tue Dec 28 13:54:37 UTC 2021


Output from db-03-db (DB 03) ..
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.000295
         Position: 41834650
     Binlog_Do_DB: <databases>
 Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
Executed_Gtid_Set: 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: db04
                  Master_User: reple
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000191
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 40328871
               Relay_Log_File: db03-relay-bin.000588
                Relay_Log_Pos: 40329084
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000191
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 40328871
              Relay_Log_Space: 40329337
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 2
                  Master_UUID: 20aa3d73-64ad-11ec-a86d-0050560200ee
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
Tue Dec 28 13:54:34 UTC 2021
```

So my question simply is how can this actually occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a VMWare setting issue.

From what the tech explained to me, they were letting the old packets/connections to reconnect instead of letting it make a new connection. Thats why MySQL was unable to "see" any new data.